# What happens if a naval invasion is repelled?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

I.e. if a unit runs out of organization while attacking the coast. Does it die or does it return to the port from which the invasion was started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They return to the port from which the invasion was started.